# Can I put my accepted paper on arXiv before it appears on the proceedings

Tags: publications, computer-science, paper-submission, arxiv, preprint

I have a paper accepted to appear in a CS conference proceedings, 
Is it possible to put it on an on-line archive,
such as "arXiv" before the conference date?
Could I at least publish the pre-print?

EDIT:
The conference chair did not ask me to sign any copyrights form!

Comment: What did the conference committee say when you asked them?

Comment: Actually arXiv is a preprint site, not an after print of published papers. My only advice: Read the conference and arXiv's copy right information so carefully.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: It's not just or even primarily for preprints, and much of the arXiv's value comes from "green open access" to published papers.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent you can put articles at any stage on arXiv (provided permission from the publisher if required). There are [proposals to use arXiv as backend for peer reviewed articles](http://theoj.org). There is actually at least [one journal already using arXiv as publishing system](http://jdmdh.episciences.org). Basically, anything is possible.

Answer (score 3):

> The conference did not claim any copyrights!

Are you sure about this? Moreover, even without a copyright transfer or similar, you could have agreed to not having submitted or published the paper elsewhere. If exceptions are being made for publishing preprints, they are often explicit exceptions to clauses that forbid you publishing the article elsewhere, so this is where you should start looking.

If the proceedings are part of a series by some publisher, you may find relevant information on preprint publishability on [RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/).

If you are still uncertain, you have to ask the conference organisers. I have no experience with such CS conferences, but if journals allow the publication of preprints, this is intentional. Thus I do not see any risk in asking the organisers.

Comment: The conference CFP invites original contributions or work-in-progress for short papers. It also invites high quality works that have been accepted or submitted to a journal. Nothing mention that the paper should not be submitted to another conference at the same time.
What should I assume?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect anything, and if you're not sure, you should ask somebody who will be sure -- PC chair, or maybe someone else in your lab, because there is a lot of unwritten rules and technically illegal policies that are widely tolerated, especially in some communities.

What would happen if you put it on arXiv without a confirmation you can do so? Most likely nothing, but don't go after me if the talk gets cancelled because of this (especially since you mention the conference is open to previously published work and work-in-progress).